# iOS app update, what happens if a user skips an update

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am currently managing updates in my app with respect to the SQLite DB.

What happens if a user misses an update in the app store and try to update to the latest version.

e.g. user has v1, skips v2 update then chooses to update to v3.

Should I keep all the update scripts and then iterate through them e.g. v2 and v3 instead of just v3?

Has anybody been doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is "database migrations". Yes, you should keep track of every possible migration and do not assume that user will have consequent incremental updates of your application.